# Please help me to solve the equation $e^{-\frac{x}{0.026}}=7.477 x^2 + 0.0146 x$

Tags: transcendental-equations

This equation has $e^x$,$x^2$ and $x$ terms.So how can we solve this type of equation?

Comment: It can't be done exactly. It's possible you can get something using the [Lambert W-function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Answer (score 2):

The best way would probably be a numerical method. Try looking up numerical analysis textbooks or Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: you don't answer if it can be reduced to the Lambert W-function or not